# How does learning more about mathematics improve one's problem-solving skills?

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, education, learning

The problem-solving skills in this question can be interpreted broadly as the skill or intuition to solve mathematical problems in general, or they can mean the skills in a particular field such as analysis, algebra, combinatorics, etc. However, it should not be interpreted narrowly as one’s familiarity with a specific subject.

In mathematical logic and real analysis, one learns to think rigorously. In combinatorics, one discovers ways to build connections. Whether it is cryptography or Ramsey Theory, learning any mathematical subject can always more or less alter one’s way of thinking and improve one’s problem-solving skills. However, since I have limited time and energy, I can not learn every subject in mathematics. If increasing my problem-solving skills is my motive, what courses or subjects can have the greatest impact on the way I think about problems?

Currently, I’m reading about *Thinking Mathematically*, which is a book about the ways to approach mathematical problems. It led me to wonder what processes in learning actually contribute to one’s growth in problem-solving skills. Sure, reflecting on obstacles when attacking problems and trying to challenge oneself can result in growth. However, to what extent should one learn? One can independently prove all the theorems in books and even do every exercise. One can always learn more about a subject, but I wonder if the marginal return will decrease as one learns more. So if increasing my problem-solving skills is my objective, to what extent should I learn a subject?

Thank you!

---

From the comments and answers, I see that this answer might vary because of one’s focus. However, I agree from the answer that understanding logic is beneficial in almost every subject. Since I don’t have a focus right now, what is something similar to logic that will be beneficial to know for all subjects?

Comment: Doing math requires practice to strengthen your math muscle, and I don't see anything other than tackling as many exercises after understanding concepts and theorems helping you improve what you are searching for.

Comment: @Abel I agree, but I don't think evaluating determinants 100 times can improve one's ability much. Also, as I mentioned in the question, doing exercises is indeed one of the best ways to learn, but I don't think wasting all time doing exercises from one subject such as doing every exercise in Rudin's book is a good use of time.

Comment: Then you'd simply be wrong. Practice is essential. Doing computations might be boring, but it will help you understand how to do them. Doing every exercise in Rudin might be a bit much at first glance, but well-designed exercises will help you connect previous things you learned to new ones, and help you look at things in new and insightful ways -- and, once again, simply get used to everything.

Comment: Problem-solving skills is not a well-defined notion. Different skills are required to solve problems in different parts of mathematics. Combinatorial problems require an entirely different sort of cleverness than do differential geometry problems.

Comment: So basically you’re asking if topologists are better problem-solvers than number-theoreticians (or any other maths specialists). There is no good answer to this: you’re only going to get biased/ opinionated answers, so I’m voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer, but I write it here because it is too long for being a comment.

The answers to your questions can be a matter of taste. According to https://www.ams.org/notices/200902/rtx090200212p.pdf, we have birds and frogs among mathematicians. I always disitinguish mathematicians somehow similar to the mentioned pdf file with the following example: If you want to solve $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^4} dx $ you can consider $1=-i^2$ and do partial fractions, or you can see like Caushy from a higher dimension and use complex integrations. So, we can say some mathematicians have a geometric view and some others have an algebraic view, and of course, some others have both. I suggest if someone wants to have both perspectives, Algebraic Geometry or Algebraic Topology would be useful. Although these two subjects differ totally from one another, they are superior tools of mathematics in my opinion. So, they may give you a better intuition for daily life problems and the approaches to solving them.

Answer (score 0):

The neurological process of mathematics is logical and so is problem-solving. There exist two portions of logical use in mathematics: in practice and in rigor. Realizing logic constantly provides for better awareness when problem-solving. Intuition is more about fuzzy-logical interrelations.

As to how and why we can get better at problem-solving is left to the neuroscientist. As I like to put it, "it is one of the great mysteries of the brain."